# How to convert a while loop into a for loop?

Tags: c++, c++11

How do I change this while loop into a for loop?

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    int number;
    long int factorial = 1;

    printf("\nEnter the number:");
    scanf("%d", &number);

    do {
        factorial = factorial * number--;
    } while (number > 1);

    printf("\nThe factorial is %d",factorial);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have these parameters:

- start value is 0
- end value is 42
- increase by 2 each loop

Expressed as a `while` loop:

```cpp
int counter = 0;
do {
    printf("\nCounter is %d", counter);
    counter += 2;
} while (counter < 42);
```

To express as a `for` loop:

```cpp
for(int counter = 0; counter < 42; counter += 2) {
    // same as inside `while` loop
    printf("\nCounter is %d", counter);
}
```

So it's mostly that all the control stuff - `0`, `42`, `2` - is in one spot, in the `for` statement. The rest of your code doesn't need to change, or not change much.